# MySQL Calculate Turn Around Time

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I want to calculate the TAT vertically between the status=buyout optr and reject or optr and pass. Can anybody have the idea.

```
I have a table like this.
```

[image: I have a table like this]

Comment: can you post the expected result pls

Comment: *I have a table like this.* Provide it as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO. Also add desired output and precise MySQL version.

Answer (score 0):

Schematically (without syntax correctness):

```
SELECT t2.dte-t1.dte AS `Turn Around Time`
FROM table t1
CROSS JOIN table t2
WHERE t1.status='buyout(optr)'
  AND t2.status IN ('buyout(pass)', 'buyout(reject)')
  AND t1.dte < t2.dte
  AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM table t3
                   WHERE t1.dte < t3.dte
                     AND t3.dte < t2.dte )
```